# How to enable QUIC along with http/2

Tags: udp, http2

Recently I am in touch with this word QUIC along with http/2 which is gaining much attention in web world. Able to get many notes about QUIC but not able to find how to enable/configure/install it so that the connection goes through it. I don't know what is relevant word to use to make it work. But please help to see it in action.

I am able to upgrade to http/2 where as configuring QUIC is becoming difficult.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many implementations at the moment since it is not yet a defined specification and Google are still changing their version rather quickly (pardon the pun!).

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC#Adoption) lists the following implementations:

**Browser support**

> The QUIC code was experimentally developed in Google Chrome starting
>   in 2012, and was announced as part of Chromium version 29 (released on
>   August 20, 2013) of Chrome. It is currently enabled by default in
>   Chromium, and active sessions can be seen at
>   chrome://net-internals/#quic. There is also a browser extension to
>   indicate which pages are served by QUIC.
>
> Similarly, it has been introduced in Opera 16, it can be turned on at
>   opera://flags/#enable-quic and opera://flags/#enable-quic-https, and
>   active sessions can be seen at opera://net-internals/#quic.

**Server Support**

> As of 2017 there are three actively maintained implementations. Google
>   servers support QUIC and has published a prototype server. A Go
>   implementation called quic-go is also available, and powers
>   experimental QUIC support in the Caddy server. On July 11, 2017,
>   LiteSpeed Technologies officially began supporting QUIC in their load
>   balancer (WebADC) and LiteSpeed Web Server products. As of December
>   2017, 97.5% of websites using QUIC are running LiteSpeed Web Server.